# Conf. Interval for a simple mixture of Normals

Tags: probability, statistics

Imagine there's a prob. p=0.5 of choosing one machine or the other to take some measurements $X$ for an experiment. One machine ($N(\theta,10)$) is much less precise than the other($N(\theta,0.1)$)

If $X\sim 0.5N(\theta,0.1)+0.5N(\theta,10)$, then how do we prove that $P(\theta \in [X-5.19,X+5.19])=0.95$?

Well, by properties of the normal dist., we have $X\sim N(\theta,0.1\times0.5^2+10\times 0.5^2)$, right?

And so, $(X-\theta)/ \sqrt{2.525}\sim N(0,1)$. However, I get $P(\theta \in [X-3.1,X+3.1])=0.95$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In my use of the term, and perhaps in the way the word is used in your course, a mixture is not a linear combination. What happens is that we take a weighted sum of the **density** functions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I've edited. Thanks. Could you help me with this? ;)

Comment: For linear combination of *independent* normals (as opposed to your initial question about mixtures) your calculation looks right.

Comment: I am surprised the question did not specify independence, if it really was about linear combinations. I would expect that even a quite elementary course would be careful about that. If the course is not so elementary, it really could be about mixtures.

Comment: @AndréNicolas this was an example of how bayesian perspective is different from a frequentist perspective.  We would imagine a prob. $p=0.5$ of choosing one machine or the other to take some measurements for an experiment. I think you're right. We can assume they are independent. Could it be, in this setting, about densities?

Comment: If we are choosing between two machines to make measurements, and $X$ is a measurement by the first machine and $Y$ by the second, and $W$ is the measurement taken, then it is not true that $W=(0.5)X+(0.5)Y$. That would describe a different process, taking a measurement with each machine and using their average. The mixture notion correctly captures the choosing between two machines problem, which would make your calculation incorrect.

Comment: Your question turned out to be interesting, which a routine question about linear combinations of independent normals would not be. It would be useful to change the title, perhaps back to the original, since it really did turn out to be about something whose technical name is mixture.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Changed the title back. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first give a brief outline of the theory. Let $F_X(x)$ be the probability that the measurement is $\le x$. Let $F_S(x)$ be the probability that the measurement is $\le x$, **given** that it was taken with the first machine, and let $F_T(x)$ be the same thing for the second machine. Then
$$F_X(x)=(0.5)F_S(x)+(0.5)F_T(x).$$
Differentiating we find that
$$f_X(x)=(0.5)f_S(x)+(0.5)f_T(x).$$
You know the densities $f_S(x)$ and $f_T(x)$, so now you know $f_X(x)$. The random variable $X$ is a **mixture** of random variables $S$ and $T$.

In particular, $X$ is not $(0.5)S+(0.5)T$. Your calculation was based on the assumption that $X=(0.5)S+(0.5)T$, so is not correct.

We now give some advice about finding the bounds. We can basically forget about $\theta$. If you want to be formal, make a change of variable. But the effect is the same as taking $\theta=0$. So assume from now on that $\theta=0$.

By symmetry, we want to find the number $c$ such that $\Pr(X\gt c)=0.025$. 
This is in principle unpleasant, we do not have suitable tables. But in our case we can take a shortcut. If $X\gt c$, it will almost certainly be the second machine's fault. So the probability that $X\gt c$ is very close to $0.5$ times the probability that the second machine gives an output $\gt c$.

We therefore get an excellent approximation by choosing $c$ so that with probability $\frac{0.025}{0.5}$, a normal with variance $10$ is $\gt c$.

By the way, this gives me $c=5.2$, using $1.645$ for the $z$ such that $\Pr(Z\gt z)=0.05$.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: You are welcome. I am actually somewhat puzzled by the $5.19$ as opposed to $5.2$. If you use $1.64$ for the $95$ percentile, which some people do, then sure. But it really is much closer to $1.645$. The other term should make no practical or even impractical difference. For the standard deviation of the bad machine is $10$ times the standard deviation of the good one, so for most useful significance levels the tail is completely dominated, I think to more than  $6$ decimal places, by the bad one.